# Using GraphQL queries on React Native app via Apollo

Tags: android, react-native, graphql

I am trying to run a React Native app in android simulator and getting this error:

[image]

Here's how my app react native app is setup:

```
import React from 'react';
import { UIManager } from 'react-native';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';

import { store, client } from './src/store';
import { colors } from './src/utils/constants';

import AppNavigation from './src/navigations';

if (UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental) {
  UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ApolloProvider store={store} client={client}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={colors}>
          <AppNavigation />
        </ThemeProvider>
      </ApolloProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

and the content of `store.js`:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import ApolloClient, { createNetworkInterface } from 'apollo-client';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import reducers from './reducers';

const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface({
  uri: 'http://192.168.142.1:3000/graphql',
});

export const client = new ApolloClient({
  networkInterface,
});

const middlewares = [client.middleware(), thunk];

export const store = createStore(
  reducers(client),
  undefined,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middlewares)),
);
```

And this is my `HomeScreen.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components/native';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import { ActivityIndicator, FlatList } from 'react-native';

import FeedCard from '../components/FeedCard/FeedCard';

import GET_TWEETS_QUERY from '../graphql/queries/getTweets'

const Root = styled.View`
    flex: 1;
    paddingTop: 5;
`;

class HomeScreen extends Component {
    _renderItem = ({ item }) => <FeedCard {...item} />;

    render () {
        const { data } = this.props.data;
        if (data.loading) {
            return (
                <Root>
                    <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
                </Root>
            );
        }
        return (
            <Root>
                <FlatList
                    contentContainerStyle={{ alignSelf: 'stretch' }}
                    data={data.getTweets}
                    keyExtractor={item => item._id}
                    renderItem={this._renderItem}
                />
            </Root>
        );
    };
}

export default graphql(GET_TWEETS_QUERY)(HomeScreen);
```

and here's my graphql query: `graphql/queries/getTweets.js`:

```
import { gql } from 'react-apollo'

export default gql`
    {
        getTweets {
            _id
            text
            createdAt
            favoriteCount
            user {
                username
                firstName
                lastName
                avatar
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

I made sure that the android simulator is able to load the graphql like this:

[image]

This means that my dev pc and the simulator device is able to see the graphql server.

I've tested my query, it works as expected:

[image]

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graphql will pass the result of the query to the wrapped component in a prop called `data`, read more about [data](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/queries.html#default-result-props) structure in official apollo documentation. I think you have a problem in `props` [destructuring](http://wesbos.com/destructuring-objects/).  Now your `data` is undefined and you're trying to call `loading` on it. In `HomeScreen render` method it should be `const { data } = this.props;` not `const { data } = this.props.data;`.